# Efficient way to delete multiple documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In my PostgresDB, I'm performing a deletion operation using another table as below.

```
DELETE FROM user_records
USING to_delete_records
WHERE user_records.record_id = to_delete_records.record_id
```

`user_records` table contains around 200 million records while `to_delete_records` table contains around 5-10 million records. Everyday the `to_delete_records` table is updated with a new set of records, and have to perform the above deletion operation. (similar to deletion, insertion operations (around 5-10 million records) take place as well, hence the total dataset of `user_records` remains around 200 million)

Now I'm replacing the PostgresDB with a MongoDB, and following is the script I'm using for deleting records in `user_records` collection:

```
db.to_delete_records.find({}, {_id: 0}).forEach(function(doc){
    db.user_records.deleteOne({record_id:doc.record_id});  
});
```

As this is a loop running, seems inefficient.

Is there a better way to delete documents of a collection using another collection in Mongo?

Comment: Have you tried using [deleteMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/#definition)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `record_id` is a unique field in both `user_records` and `to_delete_records`, you can build a unique index for the field for each collection if you have not done so.

```js
db.user_records.createIndex({record_id: 1}, {unique:true});
db.to_delete_records.createIndex({record_id: 1}, {unique:true});
```

Afterwards, you can use a `$merge` statement to add an auxiliary field `toDelete` to the collection `user_records`, based on the content in `to_delete_records`

```js
db.to_delete_records.aggregate([
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "user_records",
      "on": "record_id",
      "whenMatched": [
        {
          $set: {
            "toDelete": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Finally run a `deleteMany` on `user_records`

```js
db.user_records.deleteMany({toDelete: true});
```